# Display validation error for dynamically added elements in Laravel 4

Tags: validation, laravel, laravel-4

I have a form that records serial nos of each item. The user can add or subtract the number of items, so the form could look like this:

```
<input type="text" name="serial_no[]" required />
<input type="text" name="serial_no[]" required />
<input type="text" name="serial_no[]" required />
<input type="text" name="serial_no[]" required />
//And so on. Depending on how many items the user would record
```

I validate this by iterating through an array:

```
foreach (Input::get('serial_no') as $key => val):
    $rules["serial_no.$key"] => array("regex:/^[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{4}$/", "required");
endforeach;
```

Now, if the validation fails, I want to display the errors regarding the serial nos. In my form, I have a `span` where I put all the error messages of the field. The problem is, the validation error returns this:

```
["messages":protected]=>
array(2) {
   ["serial_no.0"]=>
      array(1) {
          [0]=>
          string(41) "The serial_no.0 has already been taken."
      }
   ["serial_no.1"]=>
      array(1) {
          [0]=>
          string(41) "The serial_no.1 has already been taken."
      }
   //Other errors of other fields
}
```

How will I be able to retrieve the errors for this field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$validation->errors()-add('error.name')`
Then you can redirect `withErrors();` back to your route, in that way, you can dynamically add errors :)

To retrieve the errors use

```
$messages = $validator->messages();
```

`$messages` will be an instance of MessageBag.
then you can use `$messages->all()`, to iterate through the errors

if you need to get a specific error use `$messages->get('key')`